# What is the fastest way to deliver binary data to browser?

Tags: javascript, performance, html, binary

I'd like to deliver custom binary data to browser. They are actually images, but I need to deliver multiple versions of the same image + some metadata. Network performance should be achieved by using just a single GET request, and it should unpack fast in the browser. So far I could think of these solutions:

- image sprite (what about the metadata?)
- ZIP
- msgpack
- JSON + base64 encoding

I don't care about < IE8. I think avoiding XHR is not possible in my case, but same origin policy is making it even worse as I need to load from different (sub) domain. That could be worked around though by server routing, on the other side that prevents using CDN.

Comment: If the images are losslessly compressed you can create an image sprite and add an area to the sprite where you can store your metadata (inside the pixel values). Then you would use <canvas>+JS to read the pixel values and, thus, the metadata.

Comment: If OTOH, the image is JPG-compressed you could still use the same trick: just use 8x8 aligned constant pixel blocks and you should be good to go.

Comment: Do you want to make a downloadble file out of binary data? If so, HTML5 has a nice API for that. The downside is browser support.

Answer (score 1):

That depend on data structure, but if you need do something with this data in JavaScript - there are two (three) ways to achieve this

- JSON + base64 or escaping special characters
- XML + base64 or escaping ( Choosing between one of them depend on preferences )
- Harder one, but most effective - plain text with escaped 0 char and special marks (make three special codes - 0x20 0x40 for 0x00 char, 0x20 0x41 as mark and 0x20 0x42 for 0x20)

Comment: I don't like the idea of base64 encoding to overcome JSON or XML limitations. Could you explain that 3rd option a bit more?

Comment: if you using json, there is no need to use base64, just escape some speical codes ( eg 0 and ] for CDATA in XML or \0, \r, \n, \' in json - it may be enough ). Third option is to make data package in OWN format (Compltely binary / 0x20 0x41 at data end), replace special codes, send it, and process in JavaScript - split by 0x20 0x41 ( ' A' )

Comment: Finded out more information about msgpack - it is best for data size, but unstable

Answer (score 0):

It turned out today's (and near future - IE9) browsers have very poor support for binary data, so whatever you decide to use, it has to be encoded (encodeable?) into a Javascript String, ie. JSON+base64.

For curious minds: http://status-501.tumblr.com/post/20293218962/delivering-binary-data-to-browser